# Fit mapview to circle bounds

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I'm using the `react-native-maps` library to generate a mapview with some markers and circles around them, I would love to be able to fit the mapview to include the circles and not just the markers on the map. Has anyone got something like this to work?

Here is a snack showing the current setup I have in `react-native`

https://snack.expo.io/@jordanr/fittoelements-issue

Comment: Can you share code, screenshots or anything else to understand better your case? :-D

Comment: I added a link to an expo snack I put together showing the exact behavior

Answer (score 6):

fitToElements does not work for me too. I had to use fitToCoordinates
https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/mapview.md

```
this.mapRef.fitToCoordinates(coordinates)
```

where `coordinates` is an array of {latitude: number, longitude: number} objects

convert the circle to an array of coordinates by calling the function `get4PointsAroundCircumference` passing in the center position of the circle and the radius in Km

```js
// returns four coordinates around the circle
function get4PointsAroundCircumference(latitude, longitude, radius) {
  const earthRadius = 6378.1 //Km
  const lat0 = latitude + (-radius / earthRadius) * (180 / Math.PI)
  const lat1 = latitude + (radius / earthRadius) * (180 / Math.PI)
  const lng0 = longitude + (-radius / earthRadius) * (180 / Math.PI) / Math.cos(latitude * Math.PI / 180);
  const lng1 = longitude + (radius / earthRadius) * (180 / Math.PI) / Math.cos(latitude * Math.PI / 180);

  return [{
      latitude: lat0,
      longitude: longitude
    }, //bottom
    {
      latitude: latitude,
      longitude: lng0
    }, //left
    {
      latitude: lat1,
      longitude: longitude
    }, //top
    {
      latitude: latitude,
      longitude: lng1
    } //right
  ]
}


const points = get4PointsAroundCircumference(51.509865, -0.118092, 100)

console.log(points);

this.mapRef.fitToCoordinates(points, {
  animated: true
})
```